# Выборка данных из нескольких таблиц используя Spring Data JPA Repository и преобразование в json

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository, jackson

Всем привет!

Сейчас мне данные отдаются в таком виде:

```
[
 { 
    "id": 1, 
    "typeOfOrganization": "Администрации",
    "created_at": 1462136400000
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "typeOfOrganization": "Архив",
   "created_at": 1462136400000
 }
]
```

Эти данные берутся из одной таблицы public_organisations. Но есть другая таблица, sub_cat_of_public_org, которые относятся как один ко многим. Мне нужно, чтобы в результате был json следующего вида:

```
[
 { 
    "id": 1, 
    "typeOfOrganization": "Администрации",
    "created_at": 1462136400000
    {
      "id": 1, 
      "name_of_sub_cat": "Администрация района",
      "specialization": "Специализация 1",
      "work_schedule": "9-18",
      "phone": "156-56-89",
      "address": "Адрес",
      "created_at": "1462136400000"
    }
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "typeOfOrganization": "Архив",
   "created_at": 1462136400000
 }
]
```

Соответственно вложенные данные должны браться из второй связанной таблицы. 
Я использую jackson, hibernate, spring repository.
Сущности БД выглядят так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "public_organisations")
public class PublicOrganization {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
private int id;
@Column(name = "type_of_organization", nullable = false, length = 60)
private String typeOfOrganization;

@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created_at;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="publicOrganization")
private Set<SubCatOfPublicOrg> subCatOfPublicOrgs;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTypeOfOrganization() {
    return typeOfOrganization;
}

public void setTypeOfOrganization(String typeOfOrganization) {
    this.typeOfOrganization = typeOfOrganization;
}

public Date getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}

public void setCreated_at(Date created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}

public PublicOrganization() {

}
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_cat_of_public_org")
public class SubCatOfPublicOrg {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
private int id;


@Column(name = "name_of_sub_cat", nullable = false, length = 70)
private String nameofsubcat;

@Column(name = "specialization", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String specialization;

@Column(name = "work_schedule", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String workchedule;

@Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, length = 15)
private String phone;

@Column(name = "address", nullable = false, length = 20)
private String address;

@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created_at;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="public_organization_id")
private PublicOrganization publicOrganization;

public SubCatOfPublicOrg() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getNameofsubcat() {
    return nameofsubcat;
}

public void setNameofsubcat(String nameofsubcat) {
    this.nameofsubcat = nameofsubcat;
}

public String getSpecialization() {
    return specialization;
}

public void setSpecialization(String specialization) {
    this.specialization = specialization;
}

public String getWorkchedule() {
    return workchedule;
}

public void setWorkchedule(String workchedule) {
    this.workchedule = workchedule;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public Date getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}

public void setCreated_at(Date created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}

public PublicOrganization getPublicOrganization() {
    return publicOrganization;
}

public void setPublicOrganization(PublicOrganization publicOrganization) {
    this.publicOrganization = publicOrganization;
}
}
```

Для вывода данных использую слой сервисов:

```
@Service
public class PublicOrganizationImpl implements PublicOrganizationService {

@Autowired
private PublicOrganizationRepository repository;
public List<PublicOrganization> getAll() {

    return repository.findAll();
}

public PublicOrganization getById(int id) {
    return repository.findOne(id);
}
}
```

Контроллер выглядит так:

```
@RestController
public class PublicOrganizationController {

@Autowired
private PublicOrganizationService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/publicorgs", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
@ResponseBody
public List<PublicOrganization> getPublicOrganizations() {
    List<PublicOrganization> list = service.getAll();
    return list;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/publicorgs/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
@ResponseBody
public PublicOrganization getPublicOrganization(@PathVariable int id) {
    PublicOrganization list = service.getById(id);
    return list;
}

}
```

Подскажите как вывести вложенные данные?

Answer (score 2):

**Первый способ:**

У аннотации `@OneToMany` есть поле `fetch`, которое отвечает за стратегию загрузки помеченных полей. Имеет два значения: `FetchType.LAZY` (по умолчанию) - данные будут загружаться только по требованию. `FetchType.EAGER` - данные загружаются вместе с сущностью.

Все что вам нужно, это указать стратегию как `EAGER`.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="publicOrganization", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<SubCatOfPublicOrg> subCatOfPublicOrgs;
```

**Второй спобос:**

Вы можете переопределить метод `findAll()` и передать туда свой запрос:

```
public iterface PublicOrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<PublicOrganization, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT org FROM PublicOrganization po JOIN FETCH po.subCatOfPublicOrgs")
    List<PublicOrganization> findAll();
}
```

Comment: Привет! Первый вариант что-то не сработал, все-равно выдает теже данные из одной таблицы. А второй вариант вываливает exception: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spravka.service.PublicOrganizationService com.spravka.controller.PublicOrganizationController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: com.spravka.repository.PublicOrganizationRepository com.spravka.service.PublicOrganizationImpl.repository;                                  Может имеет значение, что база PostgreSQL?